# Apple Magic Mouse 'Successfully connected but doesnt work'

Tags: bluetooth, magic-mouse

Hi I've just installed 13.04 on my machine (but had the same problem with 12.10). The machine is a 2012 imac 21".

When I go to bluetooth settings, the system detects my magic mouse. It will allow me to input '0000' as the passkey and thinks its paired successfully. The mouse led keeps flashing however, and the mouse doesn't do anything.

When I go into the bluetooth settings the mouse shows as present but not connected and when I try  to change the swith to 'on' it wont stay on.

what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In a Terminal, type these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman

sudo reboot
```

Then will works fine. Seems it's a bug in new Bluetooth manager.

Comment: The first line, and eventually removing and re-adding the mouse should be enough. Recommending a reboot is just a tad bit too much for such a small change. Reboot should only be necessary on Kernel Updates and other things that can only be set up at boot time.

Answer (score 1):

`Blueman` needs to be installed; that's the only way it will work.

The best thing to do with the Apple mice is to replace them, I have 3 Macs, all working with remote mice from Logitech. Apple is great at hardware, lousy at mice, their trackpad is hopeless and their keyboard is not that great either, especially with Ubuntu

But even when you pair it, it will not wake the computer reliably, and will lose the pairing on occasion. The Logitech mice have never "unpaired".

Comment: are still experiencing problem with the magic mouse in ubuntu? I have just bought one, but if it gives problems, I think I will give back..

Comment: @tirengarfio I bought a Microsoft Wireless mouse with a USB dongle and it works great. Can even wake computer, battery in mouse lasts a long time!